# Open Ldap directory connect with basic authentication

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap, ldapconnection

I installed open ldap server on Ubuntu and I can get contact as anonymous.

However, I want to only get contact with basic authentication.
I can disable anonymous account and
I can login from phpldapadmin script.

But, Andorid and Macosx can't get contact from ldap server with basic authentication.

I tested following this base dn format ;

1. cd=admin,dc=ldap1,dc=companyname,dc=com,dc=tr
2. dc=ldap1,dc=companyname,dc=com,dc=tr

Username : admin

But android and mac can't login to ldap server.

How can I edit server conf. ?

Thanks

Comment: #1 appears to have a spelling error, but only you know what your admin login is. It's your server, and your configuration. Nobody else can tell you.

Comment: I think solve problem. If I use username format as "uid=admin,dc=ldap1,dc=company,dc=com,dc=tr", I can login from macos. However, I can't login from android with this username format.  I just need to learn base dn and username syntax.